# increment the name of the variable, ex: prdt1, prdt2, prdt3 ...etc

Tags: python

I didn't try anything because I don't even know where to start...

the program would associate every item of the list to the variables like (name)1, (name)2, (name)3, and so on to the number of items the list has.

```
prdt = ["WD40", "001", "oleo de carro, 1L", "liquidos", "seccao 1", 5, 30]

prdt1 ="WD40"
prdt2 ="001"
prdt3 ="oleo de carro, 1L"
prdt4 ="liquidos"
```

a program that creates a variable incremented by 1 in a for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically with python version above 3.8 you can use `eval` and walrus operator in order to achieve this behaviour. You will get variables with names corresponding to your list items

```
for idx, item in enumerate(prdt):
    eval(f"({item}{idx}:={item})")
```

If you look at this weird syntax in eval it's walrus operator := combined with a parenthesis and all that in a f-string. Very unreadable and ugly solution imho, but eval only allows for expressions, NOT compound statements (so you cannot use the regular assignment with = ).

And you have int values in your list, which will cause the above code to fail, since var name in python cannot be an int... 5=5 is not a legal code, neither are values with spaces...Overall sorry to say, but this question does not make too much sense to be honest.

**But in general it sounds like a terrible idea to be honest (whatever is your usecase). If you need to associate specific names with values you should use dict probably.**

Comment: thanks!! i will try to make using other algorythm